# Simple way to replace Dock Finder and Finder Sidebar icons?

Tags: icons, osx-mountain-lion

I am trying to do several things without getting into the 'Terminal' scenario. Is there a simple way and/or application to use to change the 'Finder' Dock icon and to change the 'Finder' Sidebar icons?

LiteIcon use to be able to change the 'Finder' Dock icon but that doesn't work in Mountain Lion.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it has been upgraded yet to support mountain lion, but i used to use CandyBar on my snow leo imac for this purpose. it can also change your dock skin

**EDIT** it turns out it *has* been updated for 10.8, and additionally it has also been made free (it was a paid app before). heres the link: http://www.panic.com/blog/2012/08/candybar-mountain-lion-and-beyond/